# Implement Custom Str or Buffer in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm working with [python-gnupg](https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/python-gnupg) to decrypt a file and the decrypted file content is very large so loading the entire contents into memory is not feasible.

I would like to short-circuit the `write` method in order to to manipulate the decrypted contents *as it is written*.

Here are some failed attempts:

```
import gpg
from StringIO import StringIO

# works but not feasible due to memory limitations
decrypted_data = gpg_client.decrypt_file(decrypted_data)

# works but no access to the buffer write method
gpg_client.decrypt_file(decrypted_data, output=buffer())

# fails with TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, instance found
class TestBuffer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.buffer = StringIO()

    def write(self, data):
        print('writing')
        self.buffer.write(data)

gpg_client.decrypt_file(decrypted_data, output=TestBuffer())
```

Can anyone think of any other ideas that would allow me to create a file-like `str` or `buffer` object to output the data to?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. But the first problem is that you need a `self` in `def write`.

Comment: Meanwhile, are you using a `stringio.StringIO` or an `io.StringIO` there? If the former, I don't see where any coercing to Unicode is happening, so you'll need to give us a [mcve] that shows the code and what happens. If the latter… well, you should still give us a [mcve] demonstrating the error, but in that case you're mixing and matching 3.x-style `io` stack with the 2.x-style file-object stack, which is doable, but can get confusing.

Comment: I want to write the decrypted contents to a stream where I can manipulate the data being written to the stream as-it-is-written.

Comment: @abarnet  I'm using stringio.StringIO(). The TypeError is being raised by the gpg library due to not passing a `str` or `buffer` obj to the `output` param.

Comment: Without looking at the docs or the source, it looks like simulating a file isn't going to do you any good here, because the library doesn't _want_ a file object, it wants a string (presumably a filename?) or a buffer. Are there docs to look at somewhere, or is the only way to figure out how to use this library to grub through the source?

Comment: @abarnert - here's the source: https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/python-gnupg/src/f16d4e17cf349cf9ee561e117262a4041e4fe2ee/gnupg.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#-1519

Comment: OK, `f output:  # write the output to a file with the specified name` Yeah, that's obviously not going to work with a file object. The first thing it does with it is calls `os.path.exists(output)`. More to the point, it looks like this is just a wrapper around subprocessing the command-line tool, so all `output=spam` does is add `--output spam` to a list of args.

Comment: It looks like it has a few ways to hook things, but none of them are complete. For example, there's an `on_data` attribute that, if set, will get called with every chunk that comes from the command line tool's stdout, which is great… except you can't pass it in `__init__`, and it you set it after `__init__` it's too late, because the subprocess is already opened and the reader thread already going. So, you're probably going to need to fork or monkeypatch the source, or file a feature request with the developer if that's beyond you.

Comment: @abarnert Happy to pay you for the Pull Request if you were so inclined. I did open an issue here: https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/python-gnupg/issues/108/decrypt-data-to-output-stream

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a subclass of one of the classes in the `io` module described in [I/O Base Classes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#i-o-base-classes), presumably `io.BufferedIOBase`.  The standard library contains an example of something quite similar in the form of the `zipfile.ZipExtFile` class.  At least this way, you won't have to implement complex functions like `readline` yourself.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments above, the gpg lib won't accept an instance of `io.BufferedIOBase` - only a `str` or `buffer`. However, I wasn't aware of this class so I thank you. It may come in handy.